# cant display unicode character

Tags: java, postgresql, unicode, unicode-string

I want to display Turkish characters stored in a PostgreSQL database in my JSP page I have included: `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />`.

I still can't see the actual Turkish characterset on screen. In the database, the string is stored as `%C4%9F%C4%B1%C4%B0%C3%B6%C5%9F%C3%BC%C4%9F%C4%B0`

When I fetch it from PostgreSQL using `resultsetwrapperobject.getstring("columnname");`, it will automatically convert it into a string like this: `\304\237\304\261\304\260\303\266\305\237\303\274\304\`

I want to know why this automatic conversion happen and how to stop this conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Can you take a look into the code of 'resultsetwrapperobject' class? May be the implementation uses a buffered reader with a default (or special) encoding.

You can use

```
public String(byte bytes[], String charsetName)
```

for converting the string

```
final String charSet = "UTF8"; // or "ISO-8859-1"
String tSrt = resultsetwrapperobject.getstring("columnname");
tStr = new String(tStr.getBytes(),charSet);
```

You also can try to set the java default fiel encoding as java system property.

> -Dfile.encoding=UTF8